# NServiceBus Tutorial Demo fails

Tags: nservicebus

I'm starting to learn NServiceBus.

First thing I read is **We show how NServiceBus guarantees reliability and extensibility**, OK :)

Downloaded RetailDemo tutorial solution from NServiceBus website https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/quickstart/

Ran it, it opens 3 console apps ClientUI, Sales, Billing.
It is supposed to send a message from ClinetUI to Sales and Billing.

However the Sales app is failing with this details (and next time doesnt work anymore even when just started):

```
2018-03-15 14:31:47.771 INFO  DefaultFactory Logging to 'C:\Users\username\Projects\Tutorials\RetailDemo\Sales\bin\Debug\net461\' with level Info
2018-03-15 14:31:48.014 INFO  NServiceBus.LicenseManager No valid license could be found, falling back to trial license with start date '3/12/2018'

2018-03-15 14:31:48.114 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus performance counter for '# of msgs pulled from the input queue /sec' is not set up correctly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters documentation.
2018-03-15 14:31:48.121 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus performance counter for '# of msgs successfully processed / sec' is not set up correctly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters documentation.
2018-03-15 14:31:48.128 INFO  NServiceBus.PerformanceCounterHelper NServiceBus performance counter for '# of msgs failures / sec' is not set up correctly. To rectify this problem, consult the NServiceBus performance counters documentation.
Press Enter to exit.
2018-03-15 14:31:48.365 INFO  Sales.PlaceOrderHandler Received PlaceOrder, OrderId = d299afed-5b85-4d74-97e8-0d48d9bcd653
2018-03-15 14:31:48.371 INFO  Sales.PlaceOrderHandler Publishing OrderPlaced, OrderId = d299afed-5b85-4d74-97e8-0d48d9bcd653
2018-03-15 14:31:48.495 FATAL NServiceBus Failure while trying to process C:\Users\username\Projects\Tutorials\RetailDemo\.learningtransport\Sales\f37361c2-e95e-4a8a-be81-29a72574c646.metadata.txt
System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Projects\Tutorials\RetailDemo\.learningtransport\Sales\.pending\c687e34a-4a0e-405a-bce2-25515b419778' is denied.
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalMove(String sourceDirName, String destDirName, Boolean checkHost)
   at NServiceBus.DirectoryBasedTransaction.Commit()
   at NServiceBus.LearningTransportMessagePump.<ProcessFile>d__9.MoveNext()
2018-03-15 14:31:48.503 INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus Initiating shutdown.
2018-03-15 14:31:48.517 INFO  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus Shutdown complete.
```

I guess the key reason is

```
2018-03-15 14:31:48.495 FATAL NServiceBus Failure while trying to process C:\Users\username\Projects\Tutorials\RetailDemo\.learningtransport\Sales\f37361c2-e95e-4a8a-be81-29a72574c646.metadata.txt
System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Projects\Tutorials\RetailDemo\.learningtransport\Sales\.pending\c687e34a-4a0e-405a-bce2-25515b419778' is denied.
```

Question - whats wrong? access is not denied, nothing holds this folder or file.

What can I do to continue learning this framework, if their demo solution fails?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to work fine.

Exception you see in the stacktrace is coming from [`NServiceBus.DirectoryBasedTransaction.Commit()`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/102cb28162f62b8d3ca4882b4b3e61017e1a6a80/src/NServiceBus.Core/Transports/Learning/DirectoryBasedTransaction.cs#L30) and is caused by `Directory.Move()`. That's a file system call, which clearly indicates that the access to `.pending\c687e34a-4a0e-405a-bce2-25515b419778` was denied.

The reason for that could vary. It could be that a previous run was unsuccessful and the folder/file is locked up. You could use a tool like [Microsoft/SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find out what process is causing the lock. Could also try it on another machine.